# Accessing pip-installed packages from PyPy

Tags: python, pip, package, pypi, pypy

I'm trying to figure out how to get PyPy up and running to test a package I author on the platform. I also know very little about PyPy's ecosystem (apparently).

My package depends on a third-party package, `termcolor`, and while it's installed from PyPI via `pip2` and `pip3`, it's not accessible to PyPy.

Is there some way of installing packages via `pip` so that they're accessible to PyPy, or do PyPy packages have to be available locally?

Comment: http://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/install.html#installing-more-modules

Comment: @ArminRigo that solves my problem. Thanks! (If you put this in an answer with a bit more formatting and detail, I'll accept it).